# If $ϕ'(x)+2ϕ(x)≤1$ for all x, then prove that for all x, $f(x)=e^{2x}(2ϕ(x)-1)$ is a decreasing function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

If $ϕ'(x)+2ϕ(x)≤1$ for all x,

then prove that for all x,
$$f(x)=e^{2x}(2ϕ(x)-1)$$
is a decreasing function.

**What I tried**

I solved the given inequality $ϕ'(x)+2ϕ(x)≤1$ like one would solve a similar differential equation by multiplying both sides by $e^{2x}$.
$$e^{2x}ϕ'(x)+2e^{2x}ϕ(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x}ϕ(x))$$
So,
$ϕ'(x)+2ϕ(x)≤1$ can be written as
$$(e^{2x}ϕ(x))≤\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+c$$
$$ϕ(x)≤\frac{\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+c}{e^{2x}}$$
$$ϕ(x)≤\frac{1}{2}+ce^{-2x}$$

For f(x) to be a decreasing function for all x, $f'(x)<0$ for all x
$$f'(x)=e^{2x}(2ϕ(x)+2ϕ'(x)-1)$$

So we need to prove
$$e^{2x}(2ϕ(x)+2ϕ'(x)-1)≤0$$
That is,
$$2ϕ(x)+2ϕ'(x)-1≤0$$

Let
$$g(x)=2ϕ(x)+2ϕ'(x)-1$$

We need to prove $g(x)$ is negative for all x.

I tried doing so using the original inequalities, and using the inequality I obtained by integrating, but I kept hitting dead ends.

Any help on how to approach the question?

Thankyou so much in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the calculation of $f'$. The correct calculation is $f'(x) = e^{2x} (4\phi(x)+2\phi'(x)-2)$. Then it is clear from the given condition that $f'(x) = 2e^{2x} (\phi'(x)+2\phi(x)-1)\leq0$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really should have been more careful. I'm new here so it would be great if you could tell me if I should edit my question now, or let it be. And how should I give you credit for picking out the error if I do edit the question?

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x)=2e^{2x}(2\phi(x)-1)+2e^{2x}\phi'(x) \leq 2e^{2x}(2\phi(x)-1)+2e^{2x}(1-2\phi(x))=0$ so $f$ is decreasing.